# Ask laravel function download in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8

There is a method in controller

```php
public function download(Request $request)
{
   $id = $request->input('id');
   $index = $request->input('index', 0);
   $photo = Photo::find($id);

   $photos_array = json_decode($photos->documentation_photos, true);
   $index = 0;
   $photos_path = $photos_array[$index];
   $file_name = basename($photo_path);
        
   return response()->download(public_path('documentation/picture/'.$file_name));
}
```

After running the code, getting next error

```
basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

is there any other solution to my case ?

Comment: What is `$photo_path`?  Is it a typo?